# do browsers refresh website DNS cache on server no response?

Tags: browser, dns, nameservers

I am trying to figure out how I can outsmart the time-to-live (ttl) if a server goes down. If every application on our devices carries a cache of queries that isn't always responsive to ttl changes, then the internet seems kinda flawed in it's ability to recover from server site failures.

So, I am curious what browsers do if the browser is unable to interact with the server. Is a standard practice of the browser to automatically send a new query to a recursive DNS server upon a no-response from the server? Or, is the error page just displayed and the browser waits for the site to go back up or the ttl time passes (or you manually reset the stub resolver)? fyi... I am not interested in discussing that last possibility.

A little more background... 
It makes sense to me that a browser might immediately delete a locally caches DNS resolution if the server cannot return a response. In my opinion, the browser should then allow DNS resolution as if a query was a primary query and let its primary or secondary DNS server handle the resolution. Yet, I am not sure that this happens.

edited... Thanks to Shalomb for letting me know that this was not a 404 error. I think that the general nature of the question remains the same. Though, I have removed a reference to the 404 error code.

Comment: I wonder if this stems from a misunderstanding of the HTTP status code [404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404). A `404` does not indicate a no-response or that the server is unresolvable in DNS or even indeed that the site has had a failures. It simply means the HTTP server got a request from the client for a resource it *could not find* - and this in turn implies that DNS has functioned normally and the client was able to successfully establish a TCP connection. It typically suggests a server side problem and I doubt browsers ought do anything clever in DNS when a `404` encountered.

Comment: May indeed be a misunderstanding of the 404 code. The question is the same. It's not one of what the browser "ought" to do, but one of what the browser does when the server is down.

Comment: But the server isn't down when a 404 is returned. Its up and functioning normally as far as DNS, TCP and HTTP are concerned - that's the point. It could be the reason for a 404 is that the server resource (Web page, api, etc) is unavailable or administratively set that way but then   it's really for the site administrator to resolve server side. OTOH, it could be that the site is being moved to a new IP address but then the best practice is for the site admin to lower DNS TTLs while the transition is happening. Browsers reacting to the latter would overwhelm dns servers in a frowned upon way.

Comment: Haven't posted in a while. My little inbox icon keeps showing a red number on the box. Not sure if that means 1 new unread comment or 1 new downvote. They should change that if it is the former because I open the question with an attitude of the latter.

Comment: So 404 aside. You think that the browsers do not look at least one more time if the server is not available or cannot reply?

Comment: OK, this changes the nature of the question if we consider failures even before a client-server connection is made. If a DNS lookup fails due to a record not found (NXDOMAIN) - DNS caches/clients are expected to honour [Negative Caching of DNS Queries (DNS NCACHE)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2308) where the TTL for the negative cache is derived from the SOA record set on the DNS zone. For DNS server failures (SERVFAIL), the RFCs suggest these MAY be cached but I don't remember if there is mandated caching behaviour is but it looks like consensus is these responses are cached for 5 minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176525/discussion-between-shalomb-and-jsfa11).

Comment: **how I can outsmart the time-to-live (ttl) if a server goes down.** the DNS just by itself can not be used for failover the way you think it could. And like written in comments you seem to confuse things happening at lower levels of the stack (DNS queries, TCP/IP failures) with things happening far higher (HTTP exchanges and 404 error messages)